# Create only one div while iterating using v-for

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I have list of items, where some of them need to be packed inside same `div` so they could form a dropdown section. It looks something like this:

```
<span v-for="item in items">
   <div v-if="item.dropdown" class="dropdown">
     <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" 
         data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
         Dropdown button
     </button>
     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" :href="item.href">
     </div>
   </div>
   <span v-else>
   ...
   </span>
</span>
```

Basically, I want to group those items with `dropdown` flag to same div, with a button on which anchor tags will be shown. In `v-else` part are those anchors which should not be added to dropdown.

Is it even possible to do this through template?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: But how, when I do it this way, I am getting `div` created for every single element in iteration, instead of generating it only once and later filling it with every new element which satisfy the condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no analog to "push" in vue template. So the only way is to use two loops. One for dropdown items and the other for the rest.

```
<div v-for="dropdownitem in dropdownItems" :key="dropdownitem.id"> // I gess your items have an id.
...
</div>
<div v-for="item in otherItems" :key="item.id">
...
</div>

computed: {
  dropdownItems(){
    return this.items.filter(el => el.dropdown)
  },
  otherItems(){
    return this.items.filter(el => !el.dropdown)
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know I could do it this way. But the true problem is that (I haven't written it in question so I wouldn't over complicate it) instead of anchor tags, there is much more complicated (user defined) components being created. So I want to find a way to avoid duplicating that part of code. If I follow your answer, then I would have same part of code for `dropdownItems` and for `otherItems`

Comment: Duplicated code is not a problem in a vue template. it is a reason to move that code to another component, and import it wherever you need it.